# What is the different?

Tags: python-3.7

I can't find the different between these codes as below:

**1. Sample 1**

```
modules = ["os", "sys", "random"]
def intersection_sets(modules):
    #for module in modules:
    sets = [set(dir(__import__(module))) for module in modules]
    return set.intersection(*sets)

a = intersection_sets(modules)
print(a)
```

**2. Sample 2**

```
print(100*"=")
modules = ['os', 'sys', 'random']

def intersection_sets(modules):
    sets = [set(dir(__import__(module))) for module in modules]
    return set.intersection(*sets)

print(intersection_sets(modules))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = intersection_sets(modules)
print(a)
```

Above code, set the value returned by `intersection_sets` to `a`.
Below code, display the value returned by `intersection_sets`

```
print(intersection_sets(modules))
```

Answer (score 0):

Both code samples achieve the same result/output with two slight differences.

The first difference is in the modules list. With Python, you can write strings with single quotes or with double quotes. It does not matter as long as you close with the same symbol as you open with. You can also mix them like this:

```
modules = ['os', "sys", 'random']
```

The second difference is how you are printing the result of the function. When you call a function with a return value, the function call itself becomes equal to the return. So you could save it to a variable and print the variable as shown in sample 1, or you could just print it directly without saving it as shown in sample 2.